# Get os environment in typescript with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have operating system environment called KEY and when i called it with
`echo $KEY` in Ubuntu and it will print out the value

How can I get this value in typescript?
I already looked out for this and every one say i must call it with `process.env.KEY` in my typescript code, but if i print the `process.env.KEY` it would print `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

If your executing your TypeScript code in the node environment `process.env.KEY` should work; at least it works on my Windows 10 machine.

However, you can alternatively use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) while executing your code and set custom value to any custom code.

Let's say the typescript code looks as follows:

```
console.log(process.env.MYKey);
```

While executing the code you can use `cross-env` to set the value for `MYKey`, as follows.

```
tsc myfile; cross-env MYKey=MyVal node myfile
```

And certainly you can concisely put this invocation script in your npm run script (in package.json), and use that directly.

Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "prerun-myfile":"tsc myfile",
    "run-myfile":"cross-env MYKey=MyVal node myfile"
}
```

And execute your code using `npm run run-myfile`.

Hope this helps.